# Редактирование поста в Wordpress и расположение блоков

Tags: wordpress

Приветствую.
Как задать своё расположение блоков в wp-admin для новых пользователей?

К примеру, чтобы категории были не справа, а под редактором текста - вручную это можно делать, но как в wp задать эти значения при создании пользователя?

Answer (score 0):

Код такой:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'screen_layout_page', '1' );
```

Последний параметр '1' или '2' - другие WordPress не поддерживает.